# Is it correct to say, "this chair is made to sit on, not to lay on" and "this chair is for sitting on, not lying on"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Which of the followings are correct:

> -This chair is made to sit on, not lie on.
>
> -This chair is made to be sat on, not lain on.
>
> -This chair is for sitting on, not lying on.
>
> -This chair is for being sat on, not lain on.

I found both "**Chairs are made to be sat on.**" and "**Chairs are made to sit on.**" on Google.

Comment: Technically, all are grammatically correct, but the first and third seem the most natural  to me..

Comment: They all mean different things. As Kate says, 1 and 3 are most natural for a regular statement. Since 2 and 4 are passive voice, they shift the emphasis from the person to the chair. You might choose one of them If you are discussing the structure or material of the chair, and explaining to someone that lying on the chair damages it.